# Pandas - Need to extract data from one dataframe and add to a new column in another dataframe with different shape

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I have two dataframes. One has tens of thousands of rows.  The other has hundreds of rows.

df_1(tens of thousands of rows) (Inventory)

| Color | Size | Shape | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 2 | pear | 82 |
| Purple | 4 | heart | 85 |
| Blue | 5 | oval | 99 |
| Black | 2 | round | 91 |
| Red | 1 | heart | 67 |

df_2(hundreds of rows) (Table of standard ratings of gems with different colors, size and shape)

```
| Color    | Size     | Shape(pear)       |Shape(heart)    |Shape(oval)
                      | standard rating   |standard rating |standard rating
| -------- | -------- | --------          | --------       |----------
| Red      | 1        | 85                | 85             | 85
| Red      | 2        | 87                | 86             | 85
| Red      | 3        | 85                | 88             | 86
| Red      | 4        | 86                | 83             | 86
| Red      | 5        | 85                | 84             | 86
| Blue     | 1        | 90                | 90             | 90
```

I need to add a new column to df_1 called standard rating.  It gives the standard rating from df_2 to each row in df_1.

For row 1 in df_1 which is a red gem, size 2 with pear shape.  I'd like to fetch the standard rating of the same color gem, with the same size and shape from df_2 which is 87 and put it in a new column in df_1.

df_1

| Color | Size | Shape | ratings | standard ratings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 2 | pear | 82 | 87 |
| Purple | 4 | heart | 85 | 85 |
| Blue | 5 | oval | 99 | 90 |
| Black | 2 | round | 91 | 92 |
| Red | 1 | heart | 67 | 85 |

Any suggestions how I can accomplish it?

Comment: Could you format the `df_2` data frame example? It seems that it contains 8 columns (color, size, 3 shapes, and 3 standard ratings). However, you use only 5 hyphens (---) to create the column's header.

Comment: sounds like you need a `merge` have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to merge:

```
df_1 = df_1.merge(df_2, on=['Color','Size'], how='left')
```

Then populate a new column name 'standard rating' based on the 'shape':

```
import numpy as np
df_1['standard rating'] = np.where(df_1['Shape']=='pear', df_1['Shape(pear) standard rating'],0) 
df_1['standard rating'] = np.where(df_1['Shape']=='heart', df_1['Shape(heart) standard rating'],df_1['standard rating']) 
df_1['standard rating'] = np.where(df_1['Shape']=='oval', df_1['Shape(oval) standard rating'],df_1['standard rating']) 
df_1['standard rating'] = np.where(df_1['Shape']=='round', df_1['Shape(round) standard rating'],df_1['standard rating'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

melt df_2

```
df2 = (df_2.melt(['Color', 'Size'], var_name='Shape', value_name='Standard ratings')
       .assign(Shape=lambda x: x['Shape'].str.split('[()]').str[1]))
```

output: `df2.head()`

```
    Color   Size    Shape   Standard ratings
0   Red     1       pear    85
1   Red     2       pear    87
2   Red     3       pear    85
3   Red     4       pear    86
4   Red     5       pear    85
```

**Second**

merge df_1 and `df2`

```
df_1.merge(df2, how='left')
```